# How can I combine 2 state machines in xstate 5

Tags: xstate, xstate-react

I have a machine that handles the processus of creating a product, which is used each time a user wants to create one.

Now I want to have a more guided onboarding for my new users, redirecting them to the product creation once they have filled their personal informations.

I want those 2 machines (onboarding + product) to be inter-connected, so the next/back targets each other initial/final states.